# File mapping according to user input

Tags: linux, shell, email

I have the following code

```
#!/bin/bash
v=""
for f in a123*
do
  #   echo "Processing $f file";
  #mail -a $f -s " Test" Ab@gmail.com < /dev/null
  v=$v" -a "$f
done
mail $v  -s " Test" Ab@gmail.com < /dev/null
```

I have a procedure which converts table data into flat files and saves
 it in a directory. I need to mail those flat files according to email
 id which is being provided as input via procedure Right now I am
 hard coding the email id but I need to map the email id according to
 user input.
The mail should be sent to the email ID provided by user.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html).

Use the [`read`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read) function

```
read recipient
```

And later on

```
mail "$recipient"
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998434/read-command-display-the-prompt-in-color-or-enable-interpretation-of-backslas) how to generate fancy prompts.

BTW: use [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951506/bash-add-value-to-array-without-specifying-a-key) and not string concatenation for command line options.

```
v=()
v+=(-a)
v+=(file)

mail "${v[@]}" ...
```